# Casting between Java classes extended from common Abstract class

Tags: java, casting, abstract

I have an interesting situation that EMF forced me into:

```
abstract class AbstractDog{
   ...
}

public class Dog extends AbstractDog{
   < implemented code >
}

public class DogTemplate extends AbstractDog{
   < implemented code identical to Dog >
}
```

The code found in both Dog and DogTemplate are literally identical (don't ask - our system is very reliant on Eclipse stuff and this is the only way).  I need to cast from a DogTemplate into a Dog, but getting `java.lang.ClassCastException` when I do `Dog d = (Dog) dogTemplateInstance`.  I completely understand why this exception is occurring, so please don't bother telling me why.

What I need to know is if there is any way to leverage the common ancestor relationship between the 2 classes to make this cast happen?

Comment: In C++, this functionality is known as **multiple inheritance** which is not available in Java. :)

Comment: multiple inheritance .. my object-oriented heart starts bleeding :)

Comment: @Marc Nothing non-OOP about MI. The diamond problem is specifically an OOP issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way a `DogTemplate` can be cast to a `Dog`, since `Dog` doesn't even extend `DogTemplate`. Only a Dog instance can be cast to a Dog.

You could create a new Dog instance using a constructor which would copy all the fields of DogTemplate to Dog, if it's possible. Or you could use a common interface to both classes.

Answer (score 0):

Make the dog and dogTemplate implements the same interface.  in this interface, declare the public contract/behavior of Dog.

Then you will be able to cast DogTemplate -> IDog.